# Issue with php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

When I try to run following command,

```
 php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

It says,

> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'mysys_dve.#sql-7fc_4'

Also I clear cache and even restart machine but same thing happened over and over again.

Comment: What's change did you made to your schema?

Comment: It could be a FK error - try removing foreign keys manually, then Doctrine will rebuild them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tables structure : you have to make sure that, when a field points to an *id*, both are `signed` or `unsigned`.

Mysql can't make foreign keys when the two fields don't have exactly the same parameters.